# Error while updating a numeric field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a field which is declared as numeric in PostgreSQL. I have created one table namely `content_topic_mapping` and in it one column `processing_status`.
The description of the field is :-

```
processing_status numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

When I am trying to update the following field with the below query :-

```
update content_topic_mapping set processing_status=1
```

I am being given an error

> ERROR:  no conversion function from character varying to numeric.

I have tried searching the web, but all suggest doing a cast. I am not sure why to do a cast. 
Any suggestion why I am unable to do a simple update in database.

Comment: The error message does not match your statement. Are you sure you are not running something like `update content_topic_mapping set processing_status='1'`? Or maybe you are using a prepared statement with a parameter placeholder? The statement you have shown, will _not_ generate that error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70ad7/1 Btw: If you only want to store integers, you should better use the data type `integer`.

Comment: Just prepared a SQL FIddle myself for this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/99e44/1/0

As you can see, it works fine. I would suggest you heed a_horse_with_no_name's comment...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the update stmnt what I have provided is the one I am using without any change. Also would like to state here that I am using Postgre 8.4 . I am also not sure why its throwing error.

Comment: can you show the results of a `\d+ content_topic_mapping` as issued in PSQL

Comment: \d+ table_name is not supported in my psql.I have given the following query to get the description :-                                             *select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'content_topic_mapping'; *                                                                                   and the output is                                                "content_topic_mapping_id";"numeric";
"topic_content_url_mapping_id";"numeric";
"matchid";"character varying";100
"processing_status";"numeric";
"content_status";"numeric";

Comment: \d+ is supported in Postgresql 8.4.  Perhaps you're not on the version you think you are.   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html

Comment: @Gary I have checked again using the query select version() which has given the result "EnterpriseDB 8.4.3.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1400, 32-bit" . So as per the result it is indeed 8.4 version.

Comment: \d+ is a PSQL client command, it's not sent to the server.  select version() reports the server version.   For the psql version you run the command `psql -V`